# function $L_p$ iff $1\leq p<2$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Let $X=<0,1>$, take the borel sigma algebra, and the lebesgue measure. Consider $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$. Show that $g\in L_p$ iff $1\leq p<2$.

I have done this:

$\int_{<0,1>}\mid g\mid ^p d\mu = \mid x\mid ^{-\dfrac{p}{2}}.\mu(<0,1>)=\mid x\mid ^{-\dfrac{p}{2}}$. But why this is not $\infty$ iff $p<2$?

I'll appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: are you sure about "$\int_{<0,1>}\mid g\mid ^p d\mu = \mid x\mid ^{-\dfrac{p}{2}}.\mu(<0,1>)=\mid x\mid ^{-\dfrac{p}{2}}$"

Comment: What do you mean by $\langle 0, 1 \rangle$?  I assume $[0,1]$?

Comment: I did $\int_{<0.1>}\mid g\mid ^p d\mu=\int_{<0,1>}\mid x^{-\dfrac{1}{2}}\mid^p d\mu=\int_{<0,1>}\mid x\mid^{-\dfrac{p}{2}}d\mu=\mid x\mid^{-\dfrac{p}{2}}\mu(<0,1>)=\mid x\mid^{-\dfrac{p}{2}}.1=\mid x\mid^{-\dfrac{p}{2}}$

Comment: The real open interval from $0$ to $1$: $<0,1>$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lebesgue integral of a function should be a (extended) real number, not a function; so the statement

$$\int_0^1 |g|^p d\mu = |x|^{-p/2} \mu([0,1])$$

is not correct.

---

One way to proceed here is to reduce this to an integral that can be computed in the classical way using a Riemann integral: If we have a continuous (or almost continuous) function that's bounded, we can just integrate like in ordinary calculus. Now notice that by the Monotone Convergence Theorem,

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 |g|^p d\mu &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\epsilon}^1 |g|^p d\mu \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\epsilon}^1 x^{-p/2} d\mu \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{x^{1 - p/2}}{1 - p/2} \Big|_{\epsilon}^1
\end{align*}

and this limit can be computed directly (namely, the relevant cases to study are based on the sign of $1 - p/2$, or how $p$ compares to $2$).